# Deploy flask in production with GeventWSGI and Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, deployment, wsgi, gevent

i actually have a rest api written in python with flask and flaskrestful extension.
I use gevent WSGI

```
def runserver():
api.debug = True
http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), api)
http_server.start()
```

All works like a charm on my machine.
I want go in production on a linux vm,on the internet i searched for hours,i don't choosed mod_wsgi because gevent doesn't work properly with it,so i prefer use nginx.

On the internet i saw flask apps hosted with uWSGI,my answer is i need to use uWSGI?
Even i use geventWSGI in my flask application?
How to work with this?
In case i don't need uWSGI,i only need to config nginx sites to pass the request properly to my flask app?
I'm newbie to all this so i'm a little confused.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Uwsgi in Gevent mode http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Gevent.html and then route all flask requests to it via nginx.

```
       server {
          listen 80;
          server_name customersite1.com;
          access_log /var/log/customersite1/access_log;
          location / {
          root /var/www/customersite1;
          uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
          include uwsgi_params;
          }
```

see http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html for more details

Comment: First of all thanka for the answer,i have few question,when i use uwsgi or gunicorn and then i proxy with nginx i'm ready for production? I must not change mothing in my code except of course monkey patching? I can also use default flask wsgi? And then wrap into gunicorn or wsgi? Thanka

Comment: yes you are ready for production, you should not have to change anything in ur code except for the monkey patching, you can use the default flask server as well if thats what you are asking and later switch to uwsgi, can you mark the answer as corect and upvote plz